# too many values to unpack, python, findcontours

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scikit-learn, ocr

im working on an OCR project and here I'm doing hand written digit recognition the problem i have is with the function `findcontours()`:

```
# Import the modules
import cv2
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from skimage.feature import hog
import numpy as np

# Load the classifier
clf = joblib.load("digits_cls.pkl")

# Read the input image 
im = cv2.imread("photo_2.jpg")

# Convert to grayscale and apply Gaussian filtering
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(im_gray, (5, 5), 0)

# Threshold the image
ret, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Find contours in the image
ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Get rectangles contains each contour
rects = [cv2.boundingRect(ctr) for ctr in ctrs]
```

Comment: the Error : too many values to unpack is caused by the findContours line !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation example on `findContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) shows that the function returns three values (or more technically it returns a tuple containing three values).

However you only have two:

```
ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

You could change it to:

```
_, ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

assuming you don't need the first one only the contours and hierarchy